# Facebook comment box - no buttons Like and Reply

Tags: facebook

I have included fb:comment tag to my iframe facebook app successfuly and it works fine.

Howewer, I would like to have "Like" and "Reply" buttons instead of "Message" and "Report" on every individual comment. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  It's not going to be easy because you're going to have to write your own code rather than using the limited plugin from Facebook.